# How can have multiple plots output from python, one 2D, one 3D

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, orbital-mechanics

I want to make a plot of an orbit and it's energy with respect to time. I want to have the program output a 3D figure of the orbit, and a 2D figure of the total energy against time. I have been trying to use matplotlib and get my head around subplots and such but with varying levels of success.

This is my most recent bit of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

# Create 3D plot of the satellite's orbit
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2 , subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

# Create a sphere to represent the planet
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:100j, 0:np.pi:100j]
x = r_planet * np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
y = r_planet * np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
z = r_planet * np.cos(v)
ax1.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap = 'gray', alpha=0.5)

# Plot Orbit
ax1.plot(r[:, 0], r[:, 1], r[:, 2])
ax1.set_xlabel('X (m)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y (m)')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z (m)')
ax1.set_title('Satellite orbiting planet')

# Plot Energy
ax2 = fig.add_subplot()
ax2.plot(t, E)
ax2.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Total Energy (J)')
ax2.set_title('Total Energy of Satellite')

plt.show()
```

[This is the present output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uw6L.png)

I have tried messing around with subplots and other stuff but the result always seems to be that they end up plotting on top of one another. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also you'll have to ignore my orbits violation of conservation of energy, I'm working on this! Part of having the graph is to keep testing this.

Thank you!

Comment: you create both ax1 and ax2 in the first line of code, but then create ax2 again with `ax2 = fig.add_subplot()`, which is why it overlaps ax1

Comment: your code doesnt work r_planet , r , t and E values are missing

Comment: @pippo1980 I know, I removed extra bits of code to keep the question as simple as possible but perhaps should've clarified the form of these variables

Comment: @tmdavison thank you! I knew it was something silly. I find the whole subplots thing a bit confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove the line:

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot()
```

Comment: This is great, but gives two 3D plots, rather than one 2d and one 3d

Comment: this initializes the plots as 3d
    `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2 , subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})`
you can instead do something like
`fig = plt.figure()` -> ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d') and then ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)